# Set a switch on until a flag is reached and then set the switch to off

Tags: c

What would be the best and easiest(simplest) way to do this..?

I am writing code in C or Capel (Vector CANoe)
I have a switch on a panel which I have designed in Vector CANoe , turns a motor on and off (0 == off and 1 == on) and I want to turn the motor off when it reaches its limit .. to stop the motor burning out !  (we know it has reached its limit when the a sensor says that the limit is reached (sensor = 1 for limit reached and 0 for not reached)

How would I do this?

i want to do something like this

```
WHILE (clutchMotorPower==1 & sensorClutchDisengaged !=1) 
break; 
else clutchMotorPower==0 

WHILE (clutchMotorPower==1 & sensorClutchEngaged !=1) 
break;     
else clutchMotorPower==0
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is `if(sensor) motor=0; else motor=1;` the sort of thing are you looking for? Is your code running in a loop, do you get an interrupt when the sensor state changes, etc?

Comment: The motor is a clutch motor and I want to initialise the clutch motor to 0 (off) first of all.  When the Clutch motor button is pressed then switch on the motor until the sensor = TRUE and then switch off the motor to stop any damage.  There are two sensors for clutch engaged and clutch disengaged.. The motor would switch the clutch between engaged and disengaged .

Comment: I guess the code could be a loop..

Comment: Alright. And do you have any code that you've tried and have had a problem with? If so, that should go in the question.

Comment: I have to wait for a time limit, switching the clutch motor on until the sensor engaged state is reached and turn off the motor.  Then again switch the motor on and the the wait for the clutch to be disengaged and turn off the motor once again.. Then start all over.. In a loop

Comment: Ok I will try to remember what I wrote..

Comment: while (clutchMotorPower==1 & sensorDisengaged !=1) break; else clutchMotorPower==0  while(clutchMotorPower==1 & sensorEngaged !=1) break; else clutchMotorPower==0

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about the system you're working on, so this is going to be some bare-bones code. Anyway, let's go through this step-by-step.

Assumptions:

- `button` is a variable that is 1 if the button is currently pressed and 0 otherwise.
- `motor` is a variable that we set to 1 to turn the motor on, or 0 to turn it off.
- `sensor` is a variable that is 1 when the sensor is activated, or 0 otherwise

First, we need code to toggle the motor state when the button is pressed. (Assume all code samples are inside a function called from your main loop)

```
//values of static variables are preserved between function calls
static char bActivateMotor = 0; //1 if we should activate motor, 0 otherwise
static char bButtonHeld = 0; //1 if button was pressed last loop
    //(to differentiate between button being held and it being released and pressed again)
if(!button) {
    bButtonHeld = 0; //if button is not being pressed, it can't be being held down.
}
if(!bActivateMotor) { //we aren't running the motor
    if(button && !bButtonHeld) { //button was pressed this loop (not held from previous loop)
        bButtonHeld = 1; //Don't toggle motor state next loop just because button was held down
        bActivateMotor = 1; //we should be running the motor
    }
    else {
        motor = 0;
    }
}
if(bActivateMotor) { //not else because could be activated this loop
    if(button && !bButtonHeld) { //button toggles motor; if we're running, stop.
        bButtonHeld = 1;
        bActivateMotor = 0;
    }
    else {
        motor = 1;
    }
}
```

Now, the next part is to stop the motor when the sensor has activated:

```
//values of static variables are preserved between function calls
static char bActivateMotor = 0; //1 if we should activate motor, 0 otherwise
static char bButtonHeld = 0; //1 if button was pressed last loop
    //(to differentiate between button being held and it being released and pressed again)
if(!button) {
    bButtonHeld = 0; //if button is not being pressed, it can't be being held down.
}
if(!bActivateMotor) { //we aren't running the motor
    if(button && !bButtonHeld) { //button was pressed this loop (not held from previous loop)
        bButtonHeld = 1; //Don't toggle motor state next loop just because button was held down
        bActivateMotor = 1; //we should be running the motor
    }
    else {
        motor = 0;
    }
}
if(bActivateMotor) { //not else because could be activated this loop
    if(button && !bButtonHeld) { //button toggles motor; if we're running, stop.
        bButtonHeld = 1;
        bActivateMotor = 0;
    }
    /////////////////////
    // Added Code Here //
    /////////////////////
    else if(sensor) {
        bActivateMotor = 0; //motor will shut off next loop
    }
    else {
        motor = 1;
    }
}
```

With the lack of specifics about your code, it's hard to figure out exactly what difficulties you might be having, but hopefully the algorithm above will be a good starting point.

Comment: I would do it in a bit different way but, as said we don't know how the OP's code is looking, anyway +1, happy 1k rep! :D

Comment: Thanks for that.. one thing to add.. the button to switch the clutch is just on or off.. cannot be held.  that has made the problem a lot clearer anyway.. thank you

Comment: Ah, not sure why I assumed 'button' when you said 'switch'. Well, this is the sort of thing that you'd use for a button, and a switch just makes it easier.